# preg_replace code evaluation with /e modifier

Tags: php, preg-replace, echo, pcre

I was looking for an alternative to eval() way to execute a code contained in a string variable, and noticed the `preg_replace` with the `/e` modifier.
However, code is evaluated quite weirdly.

For instance, `echo()` leads to an error in php 5.3.6:

```
<?php
$code = 'echo( \'Hello, world!\'.PHP_EOL)';
preg_replace('/(.*)/e', $code, '' );
?>
```

Error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /Users/.../test.php(4) : regexp code on line
>
> Fatal error: preg_replace(): Failed evaluating code: 
> echo( 'Hello, world!'.PHP_EOL) in /Users/.../test.php on line 4

While `print()` works, and outputs a *Hello, world!*:

```
<?php
$code = 'print( \'Hello, world!\'.PHP_EOL)';
preg_replace('/(.*)/e', $code, '' );
?>
```

Also, it seems that out of several lines of code, only the first one is executed:

```
<?php
$t=1;
$code = '$t++;$t++;';
preg_replace('/(.*)/e', $code, '' );
echo $t;
?>
```

Outputs *2*, not *3*.

**Question**: is this code evaluation within PCRE in `preg_replace()` documented somewhere?
Not found on php.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preg_replace `/e` eval does not evaluate statements, but just *a single* expression.

```
print()
```

Is an expression.

```
echo ...;
```

Is not.
And likewise anything that can be followed by a semicolon.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php for an rough overview.

Answer (score 3):

Your better off creating an anonymous function and calling it using `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Especially since in PHP 5.5 preg_replace /e is deprecated and it is suggested to replace it with preg_replace_callback.